# Is node js Node js code visible to client side

Tags: node.js

I heard that node js can be used in server side. I used jsp before. Inside jsp page java code is invisible to client. If node js is just javascript, then how it remains invisible to client?

Comment: It's server side executable code, so yes, it remains "invisible"

Answer (score 9):

First of all, Node js is not a programming language. it is a run time environment so **there is no node js code, only javascript code**. this javascript code runs in node js environment.

Just like Java is a language and JRE is a Run time Environment,
javascript is a language and Nodejs is a Run time Environment inside a machine/server.

Node.js runs on (more specifically can be installed on) various platforms (Windows, Linux, Unix, Mac OS X, etc.).

Node.js uses JavaScript on the server just like we use java servlets on tomcat server.

JSP is a piece of code embedded inside html pages which can create dynamic content by interacting with databases and JSP code is hidden from the browser.
JSP code runs on Java capable HTTP servers like apache tomcat to process.
Here, all the JSP code in turn converts to servlets and replaced with appropriate content and sent to the browser/client.

Javascript can run inside a browser with the help of v8 engine but there is no restriction that javascript only runs in browser. javascript can run inside a node js run time environment to interact with databases/filesystem etc.

Now that you mentioned JSP, so i assume you are talking about **server side rendering**.

In server side rendering, using node js,
for front end logic, we create a public folder, inside public folder, we write the javascript which should run inside browser like, animations, API calls etc.
this javascript runs inside browser and is visible to client. it should ideally not contain any sensitive information.

outside this public folder, we write all the sensitive javascript which runs inside node js server and is not visible to client as it runs on server side, in a way java servlets works.

because it is javascript at both places, we get confused.

Comment: This is a very long-winded way of saying "Server-side JavaScript used by Node.JS is not visible to browsers, but it's possible to expose certain JavaScript elements to the client using server side rendering", which has already been covered in previous answers.

Answer (score 5):

Server side code is not visible on client side.

Answer (score 2):

Your node.js code runs on the server and is *not* downloaded by the client.

As such it is absolutely not visible to the client.

The node.js process will interact with the client application by exposing webservices, e.g. /api/dostuff, usually using the [HTTP/HTTPS](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) or [Express](http://expressjs.com/) modules

You can even use modules such as [helmet.js](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet) to hide the fact the service is running node.js.

Answer (score 2):

Server-side javascript code (Node.js) is not visible to the client side.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not visible to the browser. The language is JavaScript but Node totally server-side. it's as secure as any other server environment "Node". Another thing to keep in mind that you have to use SSL and config your server to be secure.

Answer (score 1):

No, Nodejs code is not visible to client side.

To be precise Nodejs is javascript run-time environment which means it is a engine that executes the code written in javascript on server side, where as the code which is visible runs on client side (basically browers).

Answer (score 1):

No, as already said, the Nodejs code is **server side** which means it's impossible to see the code from a browser.
The only code visible from browser like when you inspect document, is the front end code. (eg: angular, react, viens etc)

Answer (score 1):

No, Server side code is not visible on client side.

Answer (score 1):

No Not Visble.
In server side scripting or programming files server file will not be visible only html and javascript files will be visible

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question - No, NodeJS Javascript code will not be visible to client (browser).

Javascript on a server is similar to any other language like PHP, JSP etc., on the server.
It's just like taking the javascript engine out of the browser and then putting it on server.
Here's a nice article on [What exactly NodeJS is?](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-exactly-is-node-js-ae36e97449f5/)

Client/Browser will not be able to see any data processing on Node unless the data was sent to client/browser from the node program running on the server.